# Clustering common words for objects

Tags: clustering, pca, simulation, k-means, multidimensional-scaling

I am currently running experiments aiming to simulate information transfer between agents. Without going into too much irrelevant detail, following the conclusion of a simulation I am left with a csv file of agent ids and their 'terms' for resources A, B and C. Here is a sample of 6 lines:

```
agent_id     A      B       C
   1      LJTHIA  JNPHG  FRMEAL
   2      PDMLP   JNPHG  FRMEAL
   3      IMKHR   OEKL   EVOUMLB
   4      PDMLP   PGMOS  FRMEAL
   5      PDMLP   JNPHG  EVOUMLB
   6      RIMUBLU VTVHKZ ELS
```

Based on this data, I want to create a cluster plot of agents with more 'similar' agents being clustered together. The current strategy I've taken (using R) is as follows:

1. Set all terms as factors
2. find a *gower* matrix
3. run classical multidimensional scaling on the gower matrix (using *cmdscale()*) with the intention of plotting the 3D data in 2D
4. run *kmeans()* with the data and a predetermined k as input
5. Plot the results

The resulting plot can be seen below:[image: Plot of agents]

Each cluster is supposed to represent different groups of agents that share common words or information thus aiming to show how clusters of information emerge when observing behavior of agents.

Now my questions are:

Does the current approach I've taken make sense?

Would it be more accurate to run PCA, or even MCA, in order to map the similarities to a 2D space?

Is there a more accurate way of finding similarities between agents based on common words?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your approach makes sense. Andrew Gelman just posted a comparison of PCA and factor analytic approaches to text data here...https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2020/08/06/varimax-sure-its-always-worked-but-now-theres-maths/ His view is that these more traditional multivariate tools work pretty well with text data. That said, a different approach could be to create a matrix of distances based on similarity metrics such as the Levensthein, here...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance Note that there are alternative metrics much less computationally intensive than it.

Comment: @user332577 thanks for the response. The article you sent in from Andrew Gelman appears to be about Varimax related and I could not find any mention of PCA or factor analytic approaches to text data. Levensthein distance was definitely an option but the specific letters of a term in the simulation are not being measured, it's more about the mapped meaning of terms to resource types.

Comment: I feel like we didn't read the same Gelman post. Varimax is an approach to rotating factors derived from PCA. Maybe read it again?